# Show a loading image when page load in c#

Tags: c#

I need to show a loading image when page load in c#.

I've tried using this solution without success, because the error is:

```
Line 72:             this.Response.Write(@"dots++;");
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Here is my code:

```
<script runat="server">  

    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        PleaseWait();
    }

    protected void PleaseWait()
    {
        this.Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=IE=8>");
        this.Response.Write(@"<style type=text/css media=all>");
        this.Response.Write(@".loading");
        this.Response.Write(@"{");
        this.Response.Write(@"text-align: center;");
        this.Response.Write(@"padding-top: 30px;");
        this.Response.Write(@"border-width: 1px solid #000;");
        this.Response.Write(@"width: 300px;");
        this.Response.Write(@"height: 100px;");
        this.Response.Write(@"-ms-filter: alpha(opacity=90);");
        this.Response.Write(@"-ms-opacity: 0.90;");
        this.Response.Write(@"border-style: solid;");
        this.Response.Write(@"background-color: #FFFFFF;");
        this.Response.Write(@"position: absolute;");
        this.Response.Write(@"font-family: Trebuchet MS;");
        this.Response.Write(@"font-size: small;");
        this.Response.Write(@"position: absolute;");
        this.Response.Write(@"top: 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"bottom: 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"left: 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"right: 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"margin: auto;");
        this.Response.Write(@"display: block;");
        this.Response.Write(@"background: url('/images/wait01.gif') no-repeat center;");
        this.Response.Write(@"}");
        this.Response.Write(@"</style>");
        this.Response.Write(@"<div id=mydiv class=loading>&nbsp;</div>");

        this.Response.Write(@"<script>mydiv.innerText = '';");
        this.Response.Write(@"</script>");

        this.Response.Write(@"<script type=text/javascript language="javascript">;");
        this.Response.Write(@"var dots = 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"var dotmax = 10;");
        this.Response.Write(@"function ShowWait()");
        this.Response.Write(@"{");
        this.Response.Write(@"var output;");
        this.Response.Write(@"output = '" + "Please wait..." + "';");
        this.Response.Write(@"dots++;");
        this.Response.Write(@"if(dots>=dotmax)dots=1;");
        this.Response.Write(@"for(var x = 0;");
        this.Response.Write(@"x < dots;x++)");
        this.Response.Write(@"{");
        this.Response.Write(@"output += '.';");
        this.Response.Write(@"}");
        this.Response.Write(@"mydiv.innerText =  output;");
        this.Response.Write(@"}");
        this.Response.Write(@"function StartShowWait()");
        this.Response.Write(@"{");
        this.Response.Write(@"mydiv.style.visibility = 'visible'; ");
        this.Response.Write(@"window.setInterval('ShowWait()',1000);");
        this.Response.Write(@"}");
        this.Response.Write(@"function HideWait()");
        this.Response.Write(@"{");
        this.Response.Write(@"mydiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';");
        this.Response.Write(@"window.clearInterval();");
        this.Response.Write(@"}");
        this.Response.Write(@"StartShowWait();");
        this.Response.Write(@"</script>");

        this.Response.Flush();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Just ... no. Remove all `Response.Write`, use ASP.NET like it's supposed to be used (using controls, not `Response.Write`) and let the browser show that it's loading. Or explain what error you actually get, though again: no, you do not want to do this. You also cannot show a loading image on a page while the page is loading, because the page needs to be loaded in order to show the image.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to show a loading image when page load.

If that is the case the you can use Jquery Load event to show a loading image.

Try this: http://jsbin.com/izetOcAP/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Using Response.Writes like that is crazy! One way you could do it and keep your hair in the process is:

**html**

```
<body class="load">
    <p>My hair is still here.</p>
</body>
```

**css**

```
.load{
    background-color:#e6e6e6;
}

.load.complete{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    this.body.className = 'load complete';
})
```

Here's a fiddle of a very quick example http://jsfiddle.net/rp6oourg/.